# Knockout Validation incorrectly validates ajax-loaded fields

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, validation, knockout.js

I have a main view with several partialViews.

When partialView is loaded (through ajax) it seems that the knockout validation validates the input, but does not assign the validationElement class to the input field. I think that ko.validation is done validating before the page is fully loaded.. Is it possible to manually call the validation?

The error array correctly shows the validation messages through console.log() and the amount is also correct. When I try to output the errors array it quickly shows the errors while page is loading then all the errors disappear.

Anyone with solution? thanks

Comment: Is the partial view using a its own viewmodel/validation, or is it run by a "main" viewmodel?

Comment: It is a part of main viewmodel.

Comment: You should post the viewModel code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a semi-solution to the problem.

Ported the PartialView(s) to [ko.templates](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) and everything works.